# Multidimensional array sort?

Tags: sort, array

If i have a set of years, retrieved by the loop, for every years can be more post ID.
Like:

```
2008 => 3,7,8
2009 => 4,5,6
2010 => 9
```

the code is:

```
query_posts('post_type=portfolio&posts_per_page=-1');
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) :
        the_post();
        $tmp_date = //get the year;
```

What's the better way to put years and relative posts ID in an array (later i need also an array sorting by year)?

Comment: ok, question was stupid and i've solved in this way:
    $projectsByYear = array(array());
and $projectsByYear[$year][] =  get_the_ID();

But how can i sort the array, by year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ksort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)`($projectsByYear)`

Of course every time you add something to the array it will need to be resorted.